# Javascript Syntax error, unrecognized expression on Radiobuttons

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

net mvc and i am trying to send my data to controller as a list. so i used a for loop:

**As an Example:**

```
@for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    @Html.RadioButtonFor(x => x.Detail[i].Point});
}
```

Result of RadioButtonFor above would be this in html:

```
<input type="radio" name="Detail[0].Point" value="1">
```

Now i am trying to use JQuery to change other fields within form base on change on radiobuttons so i wrote this:

```
$('input[type=radio][name=Detail[0].Point]').change(function () {
    var value = this.value;
    alert(value);
});
```

But it gives me this error on console:

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:
>   input[type=radio][name=Detail[0].Point]

I suspect its because of the name Detail`[0]`.Point. is there anything around to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
$('input[type=radio][name=Detail[0].Point]')
```

to

```
$('input[type=radio][name="Detail[0].Point"]')
```

You need to put quotes around the value of the name since it contains `[]` to make them literals.

Comment: problem is that my RazorGenerator Doesn't accept this... wow fix one problem another pops up..

Comment: my apologies your solution works well my vote for u :)